# How to Hiding/delete empty table view rows in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

Hello I have table view fetched the data from API

but I wanna show rows with a special condition

I tried to hide rows that I don't want it, but I don't want to show them in the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: DetailsListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(at: indexPath)
    switch self.type!{
    case "inbox":
        if inboxData[indexPath.row].delYn != "Y"{
           cell.configure(withDate: inboxData[indexPath.row].dodate, withName: inboxData[indexPath.row].deptNm, withMsgNameBottom: inboxData[indexPath.row].title)
        }else{
            cell.isHidden = true
        }
```

Comment: You could apply a filter to your datasource instead.

Comment: what type of filter should applied to database

Comment: Something like `inboxData = fullArray.filter { $0.delYn != "Y" }` (essentialy what you check in your snippet - I can only assume without additional context)

Comment: ill try it now thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not hide a cell in this method. Instead you should have a data model or some indicator which should tell the table view which rows to show & which ones to hide.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3 // only the number of rows to show
}
```

Comment: the number of rows increases depend on data come from the server

Comment: You should store the number of rows in a variable. Then whenever data is loaded from server, call tableView.reloadData() & in the numberOfRowsInSection function return that variable. In this way your data will be updated

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and this easy method works 100% 
in height, cell put the condition and if the other cell out of condition
then let the height of cell 0

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if inboxData[indexPath.row].delYn != "Y"{
            return 130
        }else{
            return 0
        } 
}
```